# How can I play an audio in React.js when a specific image gets clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want the audio to be played based on state change of a particular image.

play() is not working in my js file.

**The console prompts the error :** 
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

I wrote the following code for using audio:

```js
<audio src={audio} autoPlay={this.state.car ? "true" : "false"}/>
```

The above code works well if autoPlay="autoplay". But it doesn't acts accordingly with the given condition.

**I have made an image mapper in which what I want is on my click on certain areas, an audio should be played**

Please help.

Comment: Could you please include the code you have written so far?

Comment: Put quotes around the attribute values... `<src="{audio}" />`

Comment: Also, without knowing more we're just guessing.  Read **[ask]**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've missed `source` element:

```
<audio autoPlay={this.state.car ? "true" : "false"}>
    <source src={audio} />
</audio>
```

Or you can just pass a `src` attribute to the `audio` element itself:

```
<audio src={audio} autoPlay={this.state.car ? "true" : "false"} />
```